# Whats the difference between nextGaussian and nextDouble in java Random class?

Tags: java, random, gaussian, uniform

If I want to sample from a uniform distribution and get double values, I feel like I can use both Random.nextDouble() or Random.nextGaussian() in java. Can someone explain to me the difference please.

Comment: What part of the Javadoc for those two methods is not clear?  They return different value ranges.

Comment: You can most certainly not use nextGaussion to get a uniform distribution (at least not directly).

Comment: Actually my friend, both `nextDouble` and `nextGaussian` can return (theoretically) *any* `double` value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925566/does-java-threadlocalrandom-current-nextgaussian-have-a-limit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the Java API docs for `nextDouble`:

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

and for `nextGaussian`:

> Returns the next pseudorandom, Gaussian ("normally") distributed
>   double value with mean 0.0 and standard deviation 1.0 from this random
>   number generator's sequence.

This has to do with the probability of returning certain values. For a uniform distribution, there is an equal probability of returning every value between 0.0 and 1.0. In other words, the probability of getting a 0.0 is the same as the probability of getting a 0.5 or 0.7, etc.

For the normal distribution the probability of returned values will be according to a [normal distribution curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). The chances of getting 0.0 (the mean) are essentially far greater than getting -1.0 or 1.0 which is a standard deviation of 1.0 away from the mean. The further negative/positive you go from 0.0, the lower the probability of getting that number returned.

Comment: Note that both `nextDouble` and `nextGaussian` can return (theoretically) *any* `double` value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925566/does-java-threadlocalrandom-current-nextgaussian-have-a-limit