# Does Java ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextGaussian() have a limit?

Tags: java, random, java-8, limit, gaussian

I'm writing some software that requires the generation of random numbers normally distributed around 0, but with a reliable, known limit of +/- 10.

Consider the following Java 8 code:

```
int floorMax = 10;
int totalRuns = 1000000000;

int[] floorCounts = new int[floorMax+1];

for (int i = 0; i < totalRuns; i++)
  floorCounts[
    (int) Math.floor(Math.abs(
      ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextGaussian()
    ))
    ]++;

for (int c = 0; c < floorMax; c++)
  System.out.println(
    "# of values between " + String.valueOf(c) +
      " and " + String.valueOf(c + 1) +
      ": " + floorCounts[c]);
```

It executes on my local machine in 42 seconds:

```
# of values between 0 and 1: 682679980
# of values between 1 and 2: 271828237
# of values between 2 and 3: 42795770
# of values between 3 and 4: 2633149
# of values between 4 and 5: 62319
# of values between 5 and 6: 544
# of values between 6 and 7: 1
# of values between 7 and 8: 0
```

Besides the obvious hard limit of Java `double` value, is there a limit of nextGaussian()? Since this is being generated by random noise, I assume that the output of nextGaussian() could be any `double` value. However, with an (observed) 1 in 1000000000 chance of being above 6.0, it appears this could still be a useful solution to my problem, if a limit is enforced.

Comment: What do you mean by `absolute limit`?

Comment: Since a Gaussian distribution has no maximum value, any maximum value of `nextGaussian` would be an artifact of the finite precision of floating-point numbers and the finite number of random bits used. You should not rely on a maximum value.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you observe. By *definition*, gaussian can return *any* value, but the *probability* of a value greater than 7 is extremely low, but *extremely low* is not the same as *impossible*.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `java-8`?

Comment: @charneykaye: I don't know where you got that definition of "asymptotic limit", but it doesn't make sense and it's not a definition anyone actually uses. There isn't even anything asymptotic in your definition.

Comment: You know, if you'd actually *posted* the problem you were trying to solve in the first place instead of making bad assumptions and then insulting everyone who tried to help, we could have told you "just cap it manually, but this will theoretically introduce a tiny deviation from a normal distribution and you'll have to figure out whether that matters" 17 hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextGaussian()` can return any value that can represented by a double data type. Gaussian distribution approaches but never reaches 0 on either side. So it's theoretically possible to get a value of `Double.MAX_VALUE`, but very unlikely.

Gaussian distribution looks like this:
[image]
(http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/gaufcn.html)

The distribution stretches to positive and negative infinity, so there is theoretically no absolute limit. Since we're running in the VM, and `nextGaussian()` returns a `double`, we're constrained to the magnitude and precision that a `double` can represent.

Comment: `nextGaussian` is specified to have a standard deviation of 1, so it should produce similar distributions of results on any architectures. What do you mean by "limit"? Gaussian distribution doesn't have an absolute limit. It stretches to positive and negative infinity.

Comment: There isn't an asymptotic limit. There is a hard limit because the value must be represented by a `double`